# In golang, import cycle not allowed, is the principle really a good solution?

Tags: go, import

I had ask it in github issue yesterday, and one of the contributors say that I should ask it at this site, so I just paste my question at stackoverflow.

#### What version of Go are you using (`go version`)?

```
$ go version
go version go1.17.1 windows/amd64
```

#### Does this issue reproduce with the latest release?

yes

#### What operating system and processor architecture are you using (`go env`)?

`go env` Output

```
$ go env
```

#### What did you do?

I write simple code to try to describe real world, but "Import cycle not allowed" will compile error. So I could only rewrite the simple code to complex code.

"Import cycle not allowed" is a right principle, but it is not a principle to makes code simple, it makes code more complex.

Is it a temporary principle or a permanent principle?

Is it designed after many consider and discuss, or only for personal preference?

I ask this question, because I think in real world, everything interacts with each other naturally.

For example, a teacher enter a classroom, many students enter a classroom, then teacher choose student a to ask, then the student b ask teacher. It is a normal simple requirement.

But in golang, the below code could not compile success, because import cycle not allowed. It is so strange.

```
testgo
│  main.go
│
├─classroom
│      ClassRoom.go
│
├─student
│      Student.go
│
└─teacher
        Teacher.go
```

```golang
// main.go
package main

import (
    "testgo/classroom"
    "testgo/student"
    "testgo/teacher"
)

func main() {
    c := &classroom.ClassRoom{}
    t := &teacher.Teacher{}
    a := &student.Student{}
    b := &student.Student{}
    t.Enter(c)
    a.Enter(c)
    b.Enter(c)
    t.Ask(a)
    b.Ask(t)
    print(c)
}
```

```golang
// classroom/ClassRoom.go
package classroom

import (
    "testgo/student"
    "testgo/teacher"
)

type ClassRoom struct {
    Teacher  *teacher.Teacher
    Students []*student.Student
}

func (c *ClassRoom) AddTeacher(t *teacher.Teacher) {
    c.Teacher = t
}

func (c *ClassRoom) AddStudent(s *student.Student) {
    c.Students = append(c.Students, s)
}
```

```golang
// teacher/Teacher.go
package teacher

import (
    "testgo/classroom"
    "testgo/student"
)

type Teacher struct {
    TeacherName string
    InClassRoom *classroom.ClassRoom
}

func (t *Teacher) Enter(c *classroom.ClassRoom) {
    c.AddTeacher(t)
    t.InClassRoom = c
}

func (t *Teacher) Ask(s *student.Student) {

}
```

```golang
// student/Student.go
package student

import (
    "testgo/classroom"
    "testgo/teacher"
)

type Student struct {
    StudentName string
    InClassRoom *classroom.ClassRoom
}

func (s *Student) Enter(c *classroom.ClassRoom) {
    c.AddStudent(s)
    s.InClassRoom = c
}

func (s *Student) Ask(t *teacher.Teacher) {

}
```

Finally, it will compile error like below

```
package testgo
    imports testgo/classroom
    imports testgo/student
    imports testgo/classroom: import cycle not allowed
```

There are more examples.

In real world, Cat catch Rat, Rat escape from Cat. `package Cat` import `package Rat`, and `package Rat` import `package Cat`.

In real world, Animal eat Fruit, Fruit be eat by Animal. `package Animal` import `package Fruit`, and `package Fruit` import `package Animal`.

In real world, import cycle occur everywhere.

But in golang, import cycle not allowed.

#### What did you expect to see?

enable import cycle, just like the real world

#### What did you see instead?

import cycle not allowed

Comment: It is a permanent principle based on careful thought. Place interdependent types in the same packages or use interfaces to break cycles.

Comment: Don't create tiny packages for single types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is a permanent principle.** Circular dependencies increase compile time and GO is highly focused on fast compile time.

A solution to circular dependency is introducing a new interface in a new package. This interface should have all the methods that a circular dependent struct have and accessed by other circular dependent struct.

I found a clear notes about it https://medium.com/@ishagirdhar/import-cycles-in-golang-b467f9f0c5a0

Comment: OK, thanks for answering the question. What I know now is that the principle is permanent. And almost everyone says that it's a careful principle. So I will change my code.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct and well thought principal. If you understand and imbibe your use-case, you can avoid cycles. For eg:- student class should only have student related details, names, age, address etc etc. class should have things like capacity, address etc. There should be a separate class named schedule.go which would hold the mapping of class, student and teacher.

Comment: OK, thanks for answering the question. Since the principle is enforced, I will have to do rewrite the code to obey it, it cost much more time but there's no other solution.